# Boolean logic OR rearrangement

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Say we have the expression: (¬P v ¬Q) v (P v Q)

Am I allowed to rearrange the expression into: (¬P v P) v (¬Q v Q)?

If so, why is this allowed? Because there are all OR's in the expression?

Answer (score 0):

The "OR" logical operator has two important characteristics here: it's associative (meaning `a V (b V c) = (a V b) V c`) and commutative (meaning `a V b = b V a`). 
The first property allows you to ignore the parenthesis in a series of "OR"s, and the second lets you rearrange their order however you see fit.